# PHP bbcode recursive regex

Tags: php, regex, recursion, nested, bbcode

```
[div="desc"][1="text1"][2="text2"][3="link3"][/div]
```

And it continue could continue to a limit of 6.
How could create a regex that extract the "desc", the numbers and the texts?
I tried with php array, but i wasn't able.

Thank you!

Comment: Where is recursion in this? and will the format be the same for all subsequent texts?

Answer (score 2):

There is no recursion here - at least your example doesn't show it. If there does turn out to be recursion in your general case, regexes won't work; you will have to use a parser.

For this case, I would suggest first using preg_match_all with a regex like /[([^]]+)]/ . If you pass an array `matches` to this function, after running preg_match_all, `matches[1]` should be an array containing the strings '[div="desc"]', '[1="text1"]', etc. Once you have this array, you can loop through it using `foreach` and split each string on `=` and then do whatever you like with the two parts of the string that you parsed.